# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, listview

I am making a simple Android list view app which will show some basic name, in list view. My app is stopping unexpectedly. The logcat is showing this error.

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' 
    on a null object reference.
```

CustomAdapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    String animals[];
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, String[] animals){
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.animals = animals;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return animals.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        textView.setText(animals[i]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    String animals[]= {"Dog", "Cat", "Humans", "Monkey", "Rat", "Snake", "Elephant", "Giraffe", "Deer", "Tiger", "Lion","Cow", "Pig", "Goat"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), animals);
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
     }
}
```

Comment: which line did you get this on? basically, this is a nullpointerexception. Do you know what that is?

Comment: Any particular reason why two of your methods hardcoded return null?

Comment: I just followed a tuitorial.

Comment: Quite likely it's a bad one, or you haven't followed it exactly or far enough.

Comment: I got my mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Here you did Mistakes

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
textView.setText(animals[i]);
return view;
}
```

And

```
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return animals.length;
}
```

Screenshort
[image]